# Failed to install APK on Device with Android 13 Xamarin forms

Tags: forms, xamarin

Is there anyone have a problem for installing APK to device ANDROID with Android 13 version?
I've copy the APK into folder download device and from the device phone clicked the APK and choose to install and the installer won't work. (Package installer keeps stopping).

When try to install on android 11 version it works.
The APK was created with Visual Studio xamarin form.
And also i'm trying with debugging option (From VS) and apps was succesfully install to the device (ANDROID 13).

Please helps for this problem
thanks

Successfully installing APK on device with ANDROID 13 version

Comment: Is it working fine on Emulator? Did you try to recompile the project?

Comment: Yes... it's working fine on emulator and also testing on device with debug option from Visual Studio (USB Debugging)

Comment: I found an open issue [APK not installing on Android 12](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15055) on GitHub which related to your issue.